# Da Vinci resolve would not even start

Tags: video-editor

Anybody got luck in ElementaryOS running Da Vinci Resolve 16? I can't get it to start even.

Answer (score 1):

Try start the application up via the terminal. It might tell you what's going on.

to list applications: `$ ls /usr/share/applications`

to run one, use just the name:  `$ gtk-launch davinci-resolve`